# jvm.options IBM LIBERTY

Tags: websphere-liberty

I search a lot on the web, almost all links says define JVM custom variables in jvm.options also placed it on ${server.config.dir}/jvm.options.For example I added a variable called -DAPP_ENV=PROD. But this is getting as NULL after server startup.

Any idea?

Comment: please show some code. how are you attempting to get the variable?  `System.getProperty("DAPP_ENV")`?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you want to define an environment variable, so you have two options.

**1. Use an Environment variable**

In this case, you can define an environment variable (like $PATH) and load it in your app. Note this is not a JVM argument, and it will be set in the `bin/server` shell command used to start the server.

In the file:`${server.config.dir}/server.env`
Add the following line: `APP_ENV=PROD`
Access the value with:
`System.getenv("APP_ENV");` -> `PROD`

**2. Use a System property**

This is what you are trying to do, so I am not sure why it doesn't work for you, but here's how:

In the file:`${server.config.dir}/jvm.options`
Add the following line: `-DAPP_ENV=PROD`
Access the value with:
`System.getProperty("APP_ENV");` -> `PROD`

Note that in **both** cases these values are set at server start-up, and they are not changed dynamically (most Liberty configuration is dynamic). The JVM options and environment are sourced and set during the start script so a restart is required if you want to change either one.

My personal recommendation is go to the `server.env` route - its more generic and (to me) feels more appropriate since you are trying to influence the execution environment of the process, rather than defining behaviors or configuration of the JVM.